# Access is Denied for PowerShell access site via URL in localhost

Tags: iis, powershell

What IP I need o put in the IP Address and Domain Restriction in order to allow Windows PowerShell to be able to run `Invoke-WebRequest` to a URL for a site that is hosted on the same machine.

I am doing it for testing scheduled tasks. As for now, my IIS is configured to allow access only to my IP. I tried adding 127.0.0.1, the local machine IPv4 address and the Default Gateway, but I still get `Forbidden: Access is Denied` response.

What IP I need to use in the IP Address and Domain Restrictions in order to give PowerShell access to loading my site which is hosted on the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I cannot add comments yet. Are you able to browse to the URL normally without requiring credentials? If authentication is enabled on your site, you might want to modify your web.conf file and exclude the URL you are trying to access.